# SQL Server Management Studio: Database Attachment Failed

Tags: database, iis-7, ssms

I have publish my website in IIS7. It is running in DefaultAppPool. The Identity of this app-pool is set to LocalSystem. The IIS is running and I can run the application from IIS without any problem.

Now I want to attach the database placed in inetpub's application folder:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\EMSApplication\App_Data\ASPNETDB.mdf
```

I have added new logins in the SSMS which are: `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` and `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`.

But when I am trying to attach that database in the SSMS I am getting follwoing error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Failed to retrieve data for this request.
(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: 
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. 
(Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
------------------------------

CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\EMSApplication\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5123)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.00.5500&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5123&LinkId=20476
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggle with this sometimes when moving *.mdf/.ldf's* between computers. Often I have to fiddle with the file permission/ownership on the database files themselves for it to work.

Try giving the user account for SQL Server **full access** permissions to the ASPNETDB.MDF and if you have it the ASPNETDB.LDF file.

Also, the SQL Server account might not have access to read the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\EMSApplication\App_Data\ directory. You may have to fiddle with permissions here too.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me what is the name of the user account of SQL Server?

Comment: It's going to look something like SQLServerMSSQLUser$ComputerName$InstanceName

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and none of the solutions online helped. Eventually I found the solution - [run SSMS as Administrator](http://dotnet-programming-solutions.blogspot.com/2012/10/attach-database-encountered-operating.html).